# SWT List with NO selected item

Tags: java, list, swt, selected

```
list = new List(composite, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
```

How can i define a SWT LIST so i can DESELECT ALL the items? I have a scenario where no items must be selected at all...

The only SWT flags that seem to work are SINGLE and MULTI

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any provision for creating a list with no selectability. If it's a display-only widget, you should probably be using a `Table` or a multiline `Text` instead.

You could add a `SelectionListener` that called `deselectAll()`. That's a little cheesy but it would probably work.